# div container fading out does not work

Tags: jquery

I want that the content goes to 50% when I hover over the menu bar. For whatever reasons I don't get it done. I get it doen on a testing page where I just have 2 divs. As soon as I have more divs it does not work. Why not??? 
The page I am referring to is http://www.guntmarwolff.com/eigenschaftenv.php

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("Layer5").mouseover(function(){
          $("header1").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
      });

      $("Layer5").mouseout(function(){
          $("header1").fadeTo('slow', 1);
      });
  });

</script>


<div id="Layer5">
    <div style="position:relative; top:125px; left:480px; font-size:50px; z-index:1000;"><ul class="topmenu" id="css3menu1" name="css3menu1">
    <li class="topfirst"><a href="http://www.xy.com" style="height:26px;line-height:26px;">Home</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:26px;line-height:26px;"><span>Info</span></a>


<div id="container1">
<div id="header1" class="header1">
  <div class="navbar1" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:-40px;z-index:1200px; id="about"><img src="headeigenschaftendeserfolgs.png" border="0"/></div>
  <p>
<p>
```

Comment: first of all, your jquery selection is not correct. There are no tags named Layer5, only a div with id="Layer5". your selection should be $("#Layer5"). same goes with header1

Comment: Hi I tried that but that has no effect. What else could it be??? I am very helpless.

Comment: if your html is exactly like how it is in your post, all your divs aren't closed, which could be causing issues.

Comment: Ok I will have a look into that. Thanks for the hint. Hopefully it is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, Id's have a hash preceding their name:

id="Layer5"

css

```
#Layer5 {}
```

js (jquery)

```
$("#Layer5");
```

That fixed, you should sort your html.
This works for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#Layer5 li a").hover( function() {
       console.log("in");
      $("#header1").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
      }, 
  function () {
      console.log("out");
      $("#header1").fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

});

```
<div id="Layer5">
<div style="position:relative; top: 0px; left:80px; font-size:50px; z-index:1000;">
    <ul class="topmenu" id="css3menu1" name="css3menu1">
        <li class="topfirst"><a href="http://www.xy.com" style="height:26px;line-height:26px;">Home</a></li>
        <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:26px;line-height:26px;"><span>Info</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All my content

Comment: Hi I changed that but still no difference.

Comment: Yes, I read that but I was told that with mousover functzion it would be easier. my basic try on http://www.guntmarwolff.com/test/fadetest1.php works well but not on http://www.guntmarwolff.com/eigenschaftenv.php and I don't know what I am doing wrong!!!

Comment: Thank you that works as well now for me. Do you have an idea how I can stop it from flickering when I go to the different submenus and when I move the mouse away? I implemented your code on the tryout page: http://www.guntmarwolff.com/test/fadetest3.php

Answer (score 0):

A little off topic of the original post, but one of the advantages of JQuery is being able to easily chain together multiple events.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Layer5").mouseover(function(){
    $("#header1").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
  })
  .mouseout(function(){
    $("#header1").fadeTo('slow', 1);
  });
});
```